# infix to prefix calculation

Tags: java

I am trying to understand how to convert infix to prefix in order to write a method that will automatically calculate it for me.

Here is one I have done on my own please tell me if it is correct or what I am doing wrong:

> a%b-c-(d/e)

order of operations are:

> - Parentheses
> - Exponentiation  $
> - Multiplication, division and modulus %
> - Addition and subtraction

first parenthesis: (/de)

next  modulus:      (%ab)

subtraction from right to left: -%ab-c/de

last one: --%abc/de

```
/**
 * Calculate infix to postfix
 */
public String calcInfixToPostfix(String eq){

    char arr[] = eq.toCharArray() ; 
    String val, x,y,z, w;
    boolean answer = false, notEmpty = true;
    Stack<String> operandStack = new Stack<String>();
    Stack<String> operatorStack = new Stack<String>();

    for(char c: arr){

        val = Character.toString(c);        
        answer = isOperator(val);

        if(!answer/* is operand */){

            operandStack.push(val);

        }
        else{

                if(operatorStack.isEmpty()){

                    operatorStack.push(val);
                }
                else{

                    if( /* stack value */ (precedenceLevel(operatorStack.peek().charAt(0))) >= (precedenceLevel(c) /* input value */) ){

                        do{

                            x = operandStack.pop();
                            y = operandStack.pop();
                            z = operatorStack.pop();
                            w = y+x+z;
                            operandStack.push(w);   

                            if(operatorStack.isEmpty() /* end loop if stack if empty */){                               
                            break;
                            }
                            if(/* top of operator stack */ (precedenceLevel(operatorStack.peek().charAt(0))) <  (precedenceLevel(c) /* input value */) ){
                            break;
                            }

                        } while(notEmpty);                      
                    }

                    operatorStack.push(val);
                }
        }
    }

    do{
        x = operandStack.pop();
        y = operandStack.pop();
        z = operatorStack.pop();
        w = y+x+z;
        operandStack.push(w);

        if(operatorStack.isEmpty() /* end loop if stack if empty */){                               
        break;
        }

    }while(notEmpty);

    String out = operandStack.pop();
    return out;         
}


/**
 * Determines if the value is an operator
 * @param val
 * @return boolean is operator or not
 */
public boolean isOperator(String val){

    if(
            (val.equals(String.valueOf(add))) || (val.equals(String.valueOf(sub))) ||
            (val.equals(String.valueOf(mul))) || (val.equals(String.valueOf(div))) ||
            (val.equals(String.valueOf(mod))) || (val.equals(String.valueOf(exp))) ||
            (val.equals(String.valueOf(parL)))|| (val.equals(String.valueOf(parR)))
       )
    {           
        return true;    
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

/** 
 * Calculates a value for each operator based on it's precedence
 * ORDER OF OPERATION FOR INFIX
 * Parentheses
 * Exponentiation
 * Multiplication, division and modulus
 * Addition and subtraction
 * @param op char the value being tested
 * @return int return precedence level of operator
 */
public int precedenceLevel(char op) {
    switch (op) {
        case add:
        case sub:
            return 0;
        case mul:
        case div:
        case mod:
            return 1;
        case exp:
            return 2;
        case parL:
        case parR:
            return 3;
        default:
            System.out.println("error! invalid operator");
                break;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's correct...  Is there any programming in question here or are you just asking for help with your math homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that transformation is correct.

> I am trying to understand how to convert infix to prefix in order to write a method that will automatically calculate it for me.

For this, it's worth taking a look at the [shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). It could be used to automatically produce [prefix (Polish) notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation).

Comment: yes it is homework but it's for a program I have to write using infix to prefix and vise versa. Basically I just needed to make sure I am following through with the steps correctly. I have a program working but it only works for problems without parenthesis. Now I need get the parenthesis implemented.

Comment: added my program just in case anyone wants to see it.